# how to create the filter api using limit and offset through get method?

Tags: opencart

```
class ControllerSystemFilter extends Controller {
    public function getfilter() {
        $results = array();
        $query = $this->db->query("SELECT *, (SELECT name FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "filter_group_description fgd WHERE fd.filter_group_id = fgd.filter_group_id AND fgd.language_id = '" . (int)$this->config->get('config_language_id') . "') AS `group` FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "filter_group_description fgd  LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "filter_description fd ON (fgd.filter_group_id = fd.filter_group_id) WHERE  fd.language_id ='" . (int)$this->config->get('config_language_id')."' LIMIT 10 OFFSET 15");
        $results =$query->rows;

        if(count($results )){
            $json['success']    = true;
            $json['filters']    = $results ;
        } else {
            $json['success']    = false;
        }

        if ($this->debugIt) {
            echo '<pre>';
            print_r($json);
            echo '</pre>';
        } else {
            $this->response->setOutput(json_encode($json));
        }
    }
}
```

I am working on opencart and in this code i am trying to write the code for filter api using limit and offset through get method but when i run this code it shows me the output success:false.
how to resolve this ?

Comment: please post your code

Comment: if you click on the image description link you can find the code

Comment: putting your code on image is a bad idea. some users here has block access to image. this will make them think you dont add your code

Comment: please say me what is wrong in my code?

Comment: did you try to run the query directly in your SQL tools like workbench?

Comment: i have run the code directly in database its working but in localhost its showing json output false

Comment: try to echo $results, i think there is no result found

Comment: Array to string conversion in C:\xampp\htdocs\shop\upload\catalog\controller\system\filter.php on line 11Array

Comment: try echo json_encode($results)

Comment: it is showing this above error

Comment: []{"success":false} its showing same thing

Comment: weird, what did you echo? the $json or $results?

Comment: if i echo json than its shows false  and if i echo results it shows the empty array  []

Comment: its working now

Answer (score 0):

As discussed, the $json will have a value of `success:false` because the array is empty. It is because `$query->rows` is not a valid code to get row data. To fix this, use code below:

```
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT *, (SELECT name FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "filter_group_description fgd WHERE fd.filter_group_id = fgd.filter_group_id AND fgd.language_id = '" . (int)$this->config->get('config_language_id') . "') AS `group` FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "filter_group_description fgd  LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "filter_description fd ON (fgd.filter_group_id = fd.filter_group_id) WHERE  fd.language_id ='" . (int)$this->config->get('config_language_id')."' LIMIT 10 OFFSET 15");
$results= array();
foreach($query->rows as $row){
    $results[] = $row;
}
```

The code above will get the row data and store it to array `$results`

Note that when checking array, use `empty` instead of `count` like this

```
if(!empty($results )){
    $json['success']    = true;
    $json['filters']    = $results;
} else {
    $json['success']    = false;
}
```